# Is there a way to make text appear smaller using media query?

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile, media-queries

I am working on a app out of wordpress, I have content my site that I would like make smaller when they apear on a mobile device. (ex.titles and texts)

some titles when they get too long , they shift down to the next line and I want all titles on one straight line

47 characters are the max length of titles I allow for my website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
    p {font-size: smaller}
}
```